# Polynomial reduction: polynomial in terms of other polynomials?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, polynomial-math, polynomials, macaulay2

Consider each function below such as f, f2, f3 and f4 with the basis I. How can we express each f such that f_i=\sum a_i I_i and each a_i\geq 0?

*Example*

> We demonstrate the polynomials below with M2 and Mathematica.
>
> **Macaulay2:**
>
> ```
> i1 : R=RR[x1,x2,x3,MonomialOrder=>Lex]; 
> f=x3-x1*x2;
> f2=x3*x2-x1;
> f3=x1-0.2;
> f4=x1-x3+0.8;
>
> i5 : I=ideal(x1-0.2,-x1+0.5,x2,-x2+1,x3-1,-x3+1); G=gb(I);
> ```
>
> *We can express f3 with elements of I, namely with zeroth term*
>
> ```
> i11 : I_0==f3
>
> o11 = true
> ```
>
> *We can express f4 with I_5 and I_0*
>
> ```
> i17 : I_5+I_0==f4
>
> o17 = true
> ```
>
> *Can we express f and f2 with I?*
>
> ---
>
> **Mathematica:** f and f-2 cannot be expressed in terms of the I but f-1 can be expressed in I but negative terms so  cannot use Handelman's theorem on it.
>
> [image]
>
> but
>
> - f-2 is not non-negative (choose x3=1,x1=2 so 1-0-2=-1<0)
> - f is non-negative (x3=1 so 1-x1x2>0) and
> - f-1 is not non-negative (x3=1,x2>0 so -x1x2<0).
>
> and by [Handelman's theorem](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102689794), all computations are inconclusive because the the third term -x1 is negative. More about Mathematica aspects [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/122004/polynomial-in-compact-polytope-polynomialreduce-with-positive-poly-terms-and).

**How can we express a polynomial in terms of other polynomials and each quotient term is positive like PolynomialReduce in Mathematica but each quotient term positive?**

Comment: suggest you ask on mathematica.stackexchange.com.  BTW you should really stick with proper syntax for code examples.( I'm sure you know you cant use underscores in symbol names )

Comment: @agentp added the question to [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/122004/polynomial-in-compact-polytope-polynomialreduce-with-positive-poly-terms-and), thank you for the comment. Mathjax is unfortunately unsupported in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in this answer, I am using your terminology, in which R is the polynomial ring and RR is the ring of real numbers. I should also say that almost never use the ring RR, since computations in macaulay2 over the real numbers are not always reliable, always use the ring of rationals QQ or a positive characteristic field like QQ/(101).

Your `f` and `f2` polynomials are not linear, so you can not even write them as a linear combination of `I_0,...,I_5` (i.e. the generators of `I`).
Furthermore the ideal `I` as you defined it contains a scalar so it is what mathematicians call the unit ideal. It means `I=R`, that is the whole polynomial ring.
 So you can write `f` and `f2` as a combination of `I_0,...,I_5` but not a linear one. 
It means that `f = \sum g_i I_i` with `g_i` polynomials where at least one of them is not a number.

Remark. For an arbitrary ring R, the elements are usually called scalars, but when `R` is a polynomial ring, let's say `R=RR[x_1,...x_n]` then usually the constant polynomials (which are exactly the real numbers, i.e. elements of RR) are called scalars. This is just a common and of course confusing terminology.

Here is an example,

```
i2 : R=QQ[x_1,x_2]

o2 = R

o2 : PolynomialRing

i3 : I=ideal(x_1-1,x_2,x_1+1)

o3 = ideal (x  - 1, x , x  + 1)
             1       2   1

o3 : Ideal of R

i4 : I == R

o4 = true

i5 : J = ideal(x_1,x_2)

o5 = ideal (x , x )
             1   2

o5 : Ideal of R

i6 : J == R

o6 = false
```

You see that the ideal `I` has `x_1-1,x_2,x_1+1` so the element `(x_1+1)-(x_1-1) = 2` also belongs to `I`, so `I` has a constant polynomial which is a unit element (a unit element in a ring is an element that has an inverse) which implies that `I=R`. For a proof of this fact visit, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552173/if-an-ideal-contains-the-unit-then-it-is-the-whole-ring

On the other hand `J` does not have any constant polynomial, so `J` is not the whole ring `R`.

Comment: What is the scalar in the ideal `I`? All polynomials in the ideal $I=ideal(x1-0.2,-x1+0.5,x2,-x2+1,x3-1,-x3+1);$ are scalars, hence I=R? Even with a single polynomial of the ideal in a new ideal, I_{new}=R? Can you clarify the last sentence, perhaps with example in Macaulay2?

Comment: The scalar is 1. Since `x2,-x2+1` are in `I` so does `x2+(-x2+1) = 1`. It is a general fact that if an ideal `I` in a ring `R` has a unit element then it has all of the other unit elements and `I=R`. If you can any other question, do not hesitate to ask me.